# How to handle Rabbitmq Error shortstr_size in erlang?

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, ranch

I am using erlang client library to connect to local rabbitmq server using default connection parameters. I am getting this issue in a span of arroung Once in 24 Hours. My Erlang Application Not Able to Handle This Issue.
For My Error Logger I Getting These Message..

```
2017-08-06 12:45:03.883 [error] <0.3739.0>@rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1:shortstr_size:210 CRASH REPORT Process <0.3739.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:size([]) in rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1:shortstr_size/1 line 210
2017-08-06 12:45:03.883 [error] <0.3736.0> Supervisor {<0.3736.0>,amqp_channel_sup} had child writer started with rabbit_writer:start_link(#Port<0.2798>, 1, 131072, rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1, <0.3738.0>, {<<"client 127.0.0.1:56646 -> 127.0.0.1:5672">>,1}) at <0.3739.0> exit with reason badarg in context child_terminated
2017-08-06 12:45:03.900 [error] <0.3736.0> Supervisor {<0.3736.0>,amqp_channel_sup} had child writer started with rabbit_writer:start_link(#Port<0.2798>, 1, 131072, rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1, <0.3738.0>, {<<"client 127.0.0.1:56646 -> 127.0.0.1:5672">>,1}) at <0.3739.0> exit with reason reached_max_restart_intensity in context shutdown
2017-08-06 12:45:04.514 [error] <0.3754.0>@rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1:shortstr_size:210 CRASH REPORT Process <0.3754.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:size([]) in rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1:shortstr_size/1 line 210
2017-08-06 12:45:04.514 [error] <0.3751.0> Supervisor {<0.3751.0>,amqp_channel_sup} had child writer started with rabbit_writer:start_link(#Port<0.2819>, 1, 131072, rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1, <0.3753.0>, {<<"client 127.0.0.1:49559 -> 127.0.0.1:5672">>,1}) at <0.3754.0> exit with reason badarg in context child_terminated
2017-08-06 12:45:04.515 [error] <0.3751.0> Supervisor {<0.3751.0>,amqp_channel_sup} had child writer started with rabbit_writer:start_link(#Port<0.2819>, 1, 131072, rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1, <0.3753.0>, {<<"client 127.0.0.1:49559 -> 127.0.0.1:5672">>,1}) at <0.3754.0> exit with reason reached_max_restart_intensity in context shutdown
2017-08-06 12:45:04.846 [error] <0.3768.0>@rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1:shortstr_size:210 CRASH REPORT Process <0.3768.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:size([]) in rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1:shortstr_size/1 line 210
2017-08-06 12:45:04.846 [error] <0.3765.0> Supervisor {<0.3765.0>,amqp_channel_sup} had child writer started with rabbit_writer:start_link(#Port<0.2821>, 1, 131072, rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1, <0.3767.0>, {<<"client 127.0.0.1:60413 -> 127.0.0.1:5672">>,1}) at <0.3768.0> exit with reason badarg in context child_terminated
2017-08-06 12:45:04.846 [error] <0.3765.0> Supervisor {<0.3765.0>,amqp_channel_sup} had child writer started with rabbit_writer:start_link(#Port<0.2821>, 1, 131072, rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1, <0.3767.0>, {<<"client 127.0.0.1:60413 -> 127.0.0.1:5672">>,1}) at <0.3768.0> exit with reason reached_max_restart_intensity in context shutdown
2017-08-06 12:45:05.154 [error] <0.3782.0>@rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1:shortstr_size:210 CRASH REPORT Process <0.3782.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:size([]) in rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1:shortstr_size/1 line 210
2017-08-06 12:45:05.154 [error] <0.3779.0> Supervisor {<0.3779.0>,amqp_channel_sup} had child writer started with rabbit_writer:start_link(#Port<0.2823>, 1, 131072, rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1, <0.3781.0>, {<<"client 127.0.0.1:36301 -> 127.0.0.1:5672">>,1}) at <0.3782.0> exit with reason badarg in context child_terminated
2017-08-06 12:45:05.154 [error] <0.3779.0> Supervisor {<0.3779.0>,amqp_channel_sup} had child writer started with rabbit_writer:start_link(#Port<0.2823>, 1, 131072, rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1, <0.3781.0>, {<<"client 127.0.0.1:36301 -> 127.0.0.1:5672">>,1}) at <0.3782.0> exit with reason reached_max_restart_intensity in context shutdown
2017-08-06 12:45:05.484 [error] <0.3796.0>@rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1:shortstr_size:210 CRASH REPORT Process <0.3796.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: bad argument in call to erlang:size([]) in rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1:shortstr_size/1 line 210
2017-08-06 12:45:05.484 [error] <0.3793.0> Supervisor {<0.3793.0>,amqp_channel_sup} had child writer started with rabbit_writer:start_link(#Port<0.2825>, 1, 131072, rabbit_framing_amqp_0_9_1, <0.3795.0>, {<<"client 127.0.0.1:34055 -> 127.0.0.1:5672">>,1}) at <0.3796.0> exit with reason badarg in context child_terminated
```

I am using this Library
https://github.com/jbrisbin/amqp_client
as it having rebar. And I am using rebar for my project .

May Be I written some thing wrong, As I am very new to erlang. And this is my First project Live in Erlang. I am using ranch as tcp client Acceptor. And My Client Handler is a gen_fsm.

code snipet what I am using

```
init({Ref, Socket, Transport, Mod, _Opts=[]})->
        process_flag(trap_exit, true),
        ok = ranch:accept_ack(Ref),
        ok = Transport:setopts(Socket, [{active, once}]),
        {ok, {RemoteIp, _Port}} = inet:peername(Socket),
        lager:info("New Client Connection From ~w Socket ~w", [RemoteIp, Socket]),
        {ok, RabbitConnection} = amqp_connection:start(#amqp_params_network{}),
        {ok, RabbitChannel} = amqp_connection:open_channel(RabbitConnection),
        InitTimerRef = erlang:start_timer(30000, self(), session_init_timer_laps),
        gen_fsm:enter_loop(?MODULE, [], open, #state{socket=Socket, transport=Transport, buffer= <<>>, mod=Mod, timers=#session_timers{session_init_timer=InitTimerRef}, sequence_number=1, rabbitmq_conn=RabbitConnection, rabbitmq_channel=RabbitChannel, remote_ip=RemoteIp}).
```

Also when ever I am getting this Issue My ranch socket Listener throwing below errors.

```
<0.815.0> Ranch acceptor reducing accept rate: out of file descriptors
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you ran  `out of file descriptors` it means that you are opening too much resource without close them (Most likely connections).

you can increase your [file descriptors](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-files/), but you need to monitor your client and check the resources it is using.

**NOTE** the client you are using is a bit old, the official amqp rabbitmq client is on hex repository. (https://hex.pm/packages/amqp_client)
You should use it on your project:

`{amqp_client, "3.6.10"}`

Comment: thanks for pointing out, I found that I am not closing rabbitmq connection while exiting. Now I am properly closing them in terminate method if Open.